# limiting prepared statement to execute one query at a time

Tags: java, jdbc, prepared-statement

I am passing select query to prepared statement to get list of records . 
The problem is if i append the query to insert or truncate table , the prepared statements will execute all queries . 
example

```
SELECT INDEX.*
    ,item.*
FROM cust_sales_order_index AS INDEX
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT pkid AS item_pkid
        ,index_id
        ,item_code
        ,NAME
        ,quantity AS item_quantity
    FROM cust_sales_order_item
    ) AS item
    ON INDEX.pkid = item.index_id
WHERE (pkid = 100001);

CREATE TABLE temp_cust_sales_order_index_temp (LIKE cust_sales_order_index);

WITH temp1
AS (
    DELETE
    FROM cust_sales_order_index returning *
    )
INSERT INTO temp_cust_sales_order_index_temp (SELECT * FROM temp1);-- )  ORDER BY time_update
```

How can i limit the sql query to execute only the select query or at least to execute only one query at the time in Java.

Comment: Don't... append the query??

Comment: I use 
   prepStmt = con.prepareStatement(selectStmt);
   ResultSet rs = prepStmt.executeQuery();
this will execute the inner sql queries

Comment: how your java code look like?

Comment: A compliant JDBC driver shouldn't even allow the execution of multiple statements like that (although some drivers provide an explicit property to enable that).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i was using the prepared statement in a wrong way. here is an example of select used in prepared statement.

```
String selectSQL = "SELECT USER_ID, USERNAME FROM DBUSER WHERE USER_ID = ?";
PreparedStatement preparedStatement = dbConnection.prepareStatement(selectSQL);
preparedStatement.setInt(1, 1001);
ResultSet rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery(selectSQL )
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a good choice to make a transaction driven approach.
Once you receive connection make sure you disable autocommit property (by default its enable if i'm not mistaken)

Then, after each statement is passed to connection, make `connection.commit()` and only then, the changes will be delivered to database.